# Unit tests getting executed during integration test phase even after excluding them

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, integration-testing

I have a a unit test (`ProductDaoTest.java`) and an integration test (`ProductDaoIT.java`) in my maven application.

I would like to execute only the integration test during the `mvn verify` command call but the unit test also gets executed even after excluding it using the `<exclude>` tag in the `maven-failsafe-plugin` configuration.

How can I fix this problem?

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*Test.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                    <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Updated POM (with solution):

```
 <!-- For skipping unit tests execution during execution of IT's -->
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>integration-test</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.19.1</version>
                        <!-- Skips UTs -->
                        <configuration>
                            <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <!-- Binding the verify goal with IT -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.19.1</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <port>5000</port>
                            <path>${project.artifactId}</path>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>start-tomcat</id>
                                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <fork>true</fork>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>stop-tomcat</id>
                                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>shutdown</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>    
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

`mvn clean install` - Runs only unit tests by default

`mvn clean install -Pintegration-test` - Runs only integration tests by default

Comment: Excluding the unit tests in failsafe does not make sense cause it has the naming schema: `*IT.java` so this configuration can be removed. You can use `mvn verify -Dmaven.test.skip=true` ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Maven, `test` step is before `verify` step in the lifecycle.

So it you don't skip this step, it is bound to execute.

If you want to skip test , either use `-Dmaven.test.skip=tr‌​ue` as  khmarbaise suggested, either create a dedicated Maven profile for IT where you will ignore unit-tests in this way :

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Generally, you create a Maven profile for integration tests, so if it is the case, gathering all the configuration in a place is better that scattering it.

Comment: Was able to finally solve the problem with the use of profiles. Updated my question with answer above.

Comment: Good initiative. It could be useful to others.